# No result from FoxH

Tags: special-functions

Why the following code shows no result?

```
FoxH[{{{0.5, 0.5}, {1, 1}}, {{-0.75, 0.75}, {0, 0.5}}}, {{{0, 1}, {0.5, 0.5}}, {{-0.75, 0.75}, {1., 0.5}}}, 1]
```

Tested on `12.3.1.0` on Ubuntu and `13.3.0` on Windows 10.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
$Version
(*"13.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)"*) 

FoxH[{{{1/2, 1/2}, {1, 1}}, {{-(3/4), 3/4}, {0, 1/2}}}, {{{0, 1}, {1/
 2, 1/2}}, {{-(3/4), 3/4}, {1, 1/2}}}, 1] // FunctionExpand

(*-(3/(8 \[Pi]))*)
%//N
(*-0.119366*)
```

A code convert `FoxH` to `MeijerG` function (If that is of course possible is):

```
    positiveRationalQ[x_] := MatchQ[x, _Integer | _Rational] && 
    Positive[x]
    expandGammaProduct1[{b_, r_?positiveRationalQ}, 
    t_?positiveRationalQ] := 
    With[{p = r/t}, {p^(b - 1/2)/(2 \[Pi])^((p - 1)/2), 
    Table[(k + b)/p, {k, 0, p - 1}], p^-r} /; IntegerQ[p]]
    expandGammaProduct2[{a_, r_?positiveRationalQ}, 
    t_?positiveRationalQ] := 
    With[{p = r/t}, {p^(1/2 - a)/(2 \[Pi])^((p - 1)/2), 
    Table[1 + (a - k - 1)/p, {k, 0, p - 1}], p^r} /; IntegerQ[p]]
    positiveRationalParameterQ[al_] := 
    al === {} || (MatrixQ[al] && Last[Dimensions[al]] == 2 && 
    VectorQ[al[[All, 2]], positiveRationalQ])
    SetAttributes[foxHNormalize, HoldAll];
    HoldPattern[
    foxHNormalize[FoxH[{al_List, be_List}, {ga_List, de_List}, z_]]] /;
    MemberQ[al, {_, _?NonPositive}] || 
    MemberQ[be, {_, _?NonPositive}] || 
    MemberQ[ga, {_, _?NonPositive}] || 
    MemberQ[de, {_, _?NonPositive}] := 
    Module[{alN = al, beN = be, gaN = ga, deN = de, fac = 1, ap, bp, dp, 
    dt, gp, k, np, nt},
    (* factor out zero parameters *)
    ap = Position[alN, {_, c_ /; TrueQ[c == 0]}, {1}]; 
    bp = Position[beN, {_, c_ /; TrueQ[c == 0]}, {1}];
    gp = Position[gaN, {_, c_ /; TrueQ[c == 0]}, {1}]; 
    dp = Position[deN, {_, c_ /; TrueQ[c == 0]}, {1}];
    If[ap =!= {} || bp =!= {} || gp =!= {} || dp =!= {},
    nt = Join[Extract[gaN, gp][[All, 1]], 
    1 - Extract[alN, ap][[All, 1]]];
    dt = Join[Extract[beN, bp][[All, 1]], 
    1 - Extract[deN, dp][[All, 1]]];
    alN = Delete[alN, ap]; beN = Delete[beN, bp]; 
    gaN = Delete[gaN, gp]; deN = Delete[deN, dp];
    (* special handling for nonpositive integers *)
    np = Position[nt, _Integer?NonPositive]; 
    dp = Position[dt, _Integer?NonPositive];
    fac = Switch[Sign[Length[dp] - Length[np]],
    1, 0, 0,
    If[np === dp === {}, 1,
    (* 
    use limits if there are as many numerator nonpositives as \
    denominator nonpositives *)
    Normal[
    Series[Apply[Times, Gamma[k Extract[nt, np]]]/
      Apply[Times, Gamma[k Extract[dt, dp]]], {k, 1, 0}]]] 
    (Apply[
     Times, Gamma[Delete[nt, np]]]/
    Apply[Times, Gamma[Delete[dt, dp]]]),
    -1, ComplexInfinity]];
    If[fac === ComplexInfinity || fac == 0, Return[fac, Module]];
    (* flip negative parameters *)
    ap = Position[alN, {_, c_?Negative}, {1}]; 
    bp = Position[beN, {_, c_?Negative}, {1}];
    gp = Position[gaN, {_, c_?Negative}, {1}]; 
    dp = Position[deN, {_, c_?Negative}, {1}];
    If[ap =!= {} || bp =!= {} || gp =!= {} || dp =!= {},
    {alN, 
    gaN} = {Join[Delete[alN, ap], 
    ConstantArray[{1, 0}, Length[gp]] - Extract[gaN, gp]],
    Join[Delete[gaN, gp], 
    ConstantArray[{1, 0}, Length[ap]] - Extract[alN, ap]]};
    {beN, 
    deN} = {Join[Delete[beN, bp], 
    ConstantArray[{1, 0}, Length[dp]] - Extract[deN, dp]],
    Join[Delete[deN, dp], 
    ConstantArray[{1, 0}, Length[bp]] - Extract[beN, bp]]}];
    fac FoxH[{alN, beN}, {gaN, deN}, z]]
    foxHNormalize[expr_] := expr
    HoldPattern[
    foxToMeijer[
    FoxH[{al_?positiveRationalParameterQ, 
    be_?positiveRationalParameterQ}, {ga_? 
    positiveRationalParameterQ,
    de_?positiveRationalParameterQ}, z_], 
    f : (Inactive | Identity) : Identity]] := 
    Module[{aPar, bPar, cpl, c1, c2, denGam, numGam, rP},
    cpl = Flatten[#[[All, 2]] & /@ {al, be, ga, de}];
    If[Equal @@ cpl,
    (* easy MeijerG conversion *)
    rP = First[cpl]; c1 = 1/rP; c2 = 1;
    aPar = #[[All, 1]] & /@ {al, be};
    bPar = #[[All, 1]] & /@ {ga, de},
    (* expand out gamma factors *)
    rP = 1/Apply[LCM, 1/DeleteDuplicates[cpl]];
    numGam = 
    Replace[{expandGammaProduct2[#, rP] & /@ al, 
    expandGammaProduct1[#, rP] & /@ ga}, {} -> {{1, {}, 1}}, {1}];
    If[! FreeQ[numGam, _expandGammaProduct1 | _expandGammaProduct2], 
    Return[$Failed, Module]];
    denGam = 
    Replace[{expandGammaProduct1[#, rP] & /@ be, 
    expandGammaProduct2[#, rP] & /@ de}, {} -> {{1, {}, 1}}, {1}];
    If[! FreeQ[denGam, _expandGammaProduct1 | _expandGammaProduct2], 
     Return[$Failed, Module]];
     c1 = Divide[Apply[Times, numGam[[All, All, 1]], {0, 1}], 
     rP Apply[Times, denGam[[All, All, 1]], {0, 1}]];
     c2 = Divide[Apply[Times, numGam[[All, All, 3]], {0, 1}], 
     Apply[Times, denGam[[All, All, 3]], {0, 1}]];
     aPar = 
     Flatten[{numGam[[1, All, 2]], denGam[[1, All, 2]]}, {{1}, {2, 3}}];
     bPar = 
     Flatten[{numGam[[2, All, 2]], 
     denGam[[2, All, 2]]}, {{1}, {2, 3}}]];
     c1 f[MeijerG][aPar, bPar, c2 z, rP]]
     foxToMeijer[expr_, f_] := expr
     FoxHToMeijerG[expr_, 
     f : (Inactive | Identity) : 
     Identity] := ((expr /. (FoxH | Inactive[FoxH])[args__] :> 
     foxHNormalize[FoxH[args]]) /. (FoxH | Inactive[FoxH])[args__] :>
     foxToMeijer[FoxH[args], f])


     FoxHToMeijerG[FoxH[{{{1/2, 1/2}, {1, 1}}, {{-(3/4), 3/4}, {0, 1/2}}}, {{{0, 
 1}, {1/2, 1/2}}, {{-(3/4), 3/4}, {1, 1/2}}}, x]]
     (*-(MeijerG[{{1/4, 1/4, 3/4}, {1/12, 5/12}}, {{1/4, 1/4, 3/4}, {1/12, 5/
12}}, x, 1/4]/\[Pi])*)

     % /. x -> 1 // FunctionExpand
     (*-(3/(8 \[Pi]))*)

     %//N
     (*-0.119366*)
```

Or:

```
      FoxHToMeijerG[FoxH[{{{1/2, 1/2}, {1, 1}}, {{-(3/4), 3/4}, {0, 1/2}}}, {{{0, 
  1}, {1/2, 1/2}}, {{-(3/4), 3/4}, {1, 1/2}}}, 1]] 

      (*-(MeijerG[{{1/4, 1/4, 3/4}, {1/12, 5/12}}, {{1/4, 1/4, 3/4}, {1/12, 5/
12}}, 1, 1/4]/\[Pi])*)

      % // N
      (*-0.119366*)
```

Comment: Does not work for me. My Mathematica version is `12.3.1.0`.

Comment: @Dante  13.3.0 work.

Comment: With v13.3 on my Mac, `(FoxH[{{{0.5, 0.5}, {1, 1}}, {{-0.75, 0.75}, {0, 0.5}}}, {{{0, 1}, {0.5, 0.5}}, {{-0.75, 0.75}, {1., 0.5}}}, x] // Rationalize // FunctionExpand)` gives me the `MeijerG`

Comment: I tried on Windows 10 and Mathematica 13.3.0 but still not working.

Comment: How can I use your code in a paper?

Comment: @Dante .My  all code works.I have windows 10 and MMA 13.3.0.Try with fresh Kernel.